# Using not equal to in where clause cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Why doesn't this work?

I want to display files which are

1. available (in my case is = 0)
2. everyone (Privacy settings which in my case is =1)
3. Not equal to the author of the file

it doesn't display me anything for which the user that created it, it is supposed to show a file that is
within those conditions

it seems like I have a problem within the `'Files.user_id !=' => $auth->user_id` but I can't figure out what is wrong with it

```
$filesTable->find('all')->where(['available' => 0,'Privacy.privacy_id' => 1,'Files.user_id !=' => $auth->user_id])->contain(['Users','Privacy'])->toArray();
```

Neither of these are being displayed
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPnvk.png)

Comment: What value does `$auth->user_id` hold when you run this query?

Comment: $auth->user_id holds a value of 18

Comment: None of the records in your image will match `user_id != 18`. Two of them are 18, and one is null, which you have to have an explicit clause for if you want to be included.

Comment: How can I include the null one?

Comment: Can I do another clause like this? 'Files.user_id ' => NULL

Comment: More detailed information is available in the CookBook: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatic-is-null-creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include `null` IDs in your query, you need to match on that explicitly:

```
$filesTable->find('all')->where([
    'available' => 0,
    'Privacy.privacy_id' => 1,
    'OR' => [
        'Files.user_id !=' => $auth->user_id,
        'Files.user_id IS' => null,
    ],
])->contain(['Users','Privacy'])->toArray();
```